# How to change style of element in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html

## The Problem:

I am designing a site which uses the same sidebar on all pages, so I put the sidebar in an iFrame for easy editing later... But on each page I want the current page link in the iFrame to be in bold font... Please could you help with a JavaScript statement or function that could to this.

My current code is as follows:

#### HTML (Main Webpage):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Example Page</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTag = function(tag){
     var currentPage = document.frames['tag_list'].document.getElementById(tag+'_tag-list'); currentPage.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    };
    currentTag("home")
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <header>
    <!--All header code-->
   </header>
   <!--Sidebar (Problem)-->
   <iframe src="myframe.html" scrolling="no" id="tag_list">Your browser does not support the "iframe" element, please update...</iframe>
   <div id="content">
    <!--All content-->
   </div>
   <footer>
    <!--All footer code-->
   </footer>
  </body>
 </html>
```

#### HTML (iFrame):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Sidebar Frame</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="tag_list">
   <h2>Pages</h2>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="home_tag-list">Homepage</span></a></li>
    <!--And all the other pages-->
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Your help is much appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything within the iframe can be access by accessing the iframe's `contentWindow` property, but only if the iframe's content is from the same origin as the parent window.

Once you're at `contentWindow`, access the element just like you would normally (`document.getElementBy...`)

Comment: So can you give me an example of the javascript statement I would write? And by "the same origin" do you mean the files have to be in the same directory or on the same server?

Comment: In your case, something like `document.getElementById('tag_list').contentDocument.getElementById('home_tag-list').style.fontWeight = "bold";` - you might want to write a function to do some of that for you!

Comment: This works when I make a button onClick call the function, but when I call the function myself it doesn't work!

Comment: Has the iframe loaded before you try to call the function? If not, it won't be able to find it.

Comment: I sorted this out by using the onLoad attribute to call the function. Thanks sooooo much :D